# One attribute is updating, other is not

Tags: python, django

I am reading http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models.html, and trying to implement exercise. The exercise is:

> Update your population script so that the Python category has 128 views and 64 likes, the Django category has 64 views and 32 likes, and the Other Frameworks category has 32 views and 16 likes.

So, I did the same in population script:

```
def add_cat(name,likes,views):
c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
c.likes = likes
print c.likes
c.views = views
return c
```

The whole script is:

```
  import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python',64,128)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django",32,64)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks",16,32)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name,likes,views):
c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
c.likes = likes
print c.likes
c.views = views
return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    populate()
```

Now, I want to print the values of both likes & views :

```
>>> c = Category.objects.get(pk = 3)
>>> c
<Category: Python>
>>> c.likes
0
>>> c.views
128
>>>
```

The value of likes doesn't change, while views get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the object, for more information check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields)

```
def add_cat(name,likes,views):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.likes = likes
    print c.likes
    c.views = views
    c.save()
    return c
```

Comment: Please explain a bit. Why I need to save for likes but not for views?

Comment: You're saving the `c` object (which saves both `likes` and `views` properties of each)

Comment: but, without saving views works fine. Why does it work for views?

Comment: @learner By doing `c.likes = likes` and `c.views = views` you're are updating the `c` object just for that scope, you're not persisting that data, you need to call `.save()` method to write on DB and retrieve the updated values after.